# Making a character who gets stronger as he/she takes damage

Tags: pathfinder-1e

I had a friend ask me about a build that would get stronger as they took damage. The concept he had in mind was a melee fighter class that would deal more damage as his HP got lower. He is willing to dip into spell casting classes.

I am aware of the deathless feats but not much else that could accomplish this.

Are there any mechanical features that could produces this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In fact, there is a perfect spell from *Pathfinder Companion: Orcs of Golarion* for that:

[Bloodrage](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/b/blood-rage)

> The targets of this spell become angrier as they fight, the pain of their wounds fueling their strength. An affected creature gains a cumulative +2 morale bonus to Strength and a cumulative -1 penalty to AC for every 5 points of damage it takes (maximum +10 Strength, -5 AC) for the duration of the spell. These bonuses last until the spell expires or the target falls unconscious.

It is a 2nd-level for bards or a 3rd for clerics, sorcerers and wizards. A one-level dip won't do it, but you might want to check out the Skald (combination of bard & barbarian), one of the new classes Paizo is working on in their *Advanced Class Guide*.

Of course, the spell won't last that long and it wouldn't stack with other morale boni (barbarian rage, the skalds raging song).

Or you could just let your local bard create an item for you(with your gm's approval).

Comment: That's kind of a hilariously overpowered spell in the right circumstances.

Comment: Oh yes, it is. The best thing is that damage healed while under the effect of the spell doesn't seem to reduce the morale bonus. So you could get some damage, get strong and get a cleric to heal yourself again.

Comment: It's also the perfect spell for a Bardbarian.

Comment: Yeah... Except it doesn't stack with rage - But it is extending your rage possibilities

Comment: I'd create a barbarian with a cursed "warrior slave collar" magic item which bestows this effect...

Answer (score 7):

Options like this don't always need The Exact Rule (TM).  In this case, be a barbarian, and just trigger rage when taken to 50% of hit points. Take some rage powers that you kick in at lower HP totals. Take a level in some spontaneous caster class  and get some buffs that you "cast" with the visuals of hulking it up for a standard action. The character's rules don't have to be accessible to the character itself, they are still metatextual constructs you the player may manipulate to generate the narrative you want.

Answer (score 3):

If D&D resources are allowed, then there is a solution in PHB II, page 33: the Barbarian Alternate Class Feature *Berserker Strength*. It replaces the character's Rage with a rage-like effect after his HP gets lower than 5 × Barbarian Level, and as many times a day his HP drops that low. The rage effect ends after the character gets healed above that amount of HP, so it's kind of risky, through what the character gets may somewhat help him survive:

```
 1st+ level: +4 STR, +2 Saves, DR +2/-
11th+ level: +6 STR, +3 Saves, DR +3/-
20th+ level: +8 STR, +4 Saves, DR +4/-
```

Perhaps a dip in Crusader may improve the character's survivability (at 6+ level, to get some really good maneuvers/stances), and it also gives you Furious Counterstrike (the more damage you have in Delayed Damage pool, the more attack/damage bonuses you have).
Since you don't use gestalt rules, the best build for this character is something like *Barbarian 6/Crusader 1/Barbarian X*, since you need as much barb levels as you can get your hand onto. On the other hands, with *Barbarian 6/Crusader 4/Barbarian X* you'll get Delayed Damage Pool 10 and some nice bonuses to your saves (also, maneuvers/stances), which is nice as well

Comment: Strange that you mention crusader, and yet don't mention Furious Counterstrike.

Comment: Oh, right. Edited 8)